# Hide sensitive data from cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cognito

We are using AWS cognito for our mobile app and log all the communication between the the app and the server to cloudwatch (loglevel: INFO)

I have an endpoint which takes user's password (POST via ssl) to verify authenticity.
This password gets logged to cloudwatch logs.

I want all other communications logged so I can't turn off `Log full requests/responses data`.
Is there anyway to hide this specific data from cloudwatch logs?

Comment: you said: "I have an endpoint which takes user's password (POST via ssl) to verify authenticity. This password gets logged to cloudwatch logs." this is using cognito or a custom code?

Comment: If you have un-redacted logs that you want to send to a third party, you can use Sublime Text to retrospectively redact them - see  https://codingrob.medium.com/how-to-redact-text-from-hundreds-of-text-files-in-less-than-60-seconds-511b4b91c2d8

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use the **Advance security feature** of AWS cognito user pool using console to hide all sensitive data i.e hide specific data from the logs